# SourceLink F12 doesn't work properly in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: ide, visual-studio-2022

I recently installed Visual Studio 2022 and my F12 'Go To Definition' shortcut seems to have stopped working properly in some circumstances.  It will often either navigate to the beginning of a file, or select the wrong text in a file based on what I pressed F12 on.

Here's an example of it selecting the wrong text in a file when navigating to `SixLabors.ImageSharp.Color.Black`:

[image: wrong text]

Here's an example of it just going to the start of a file's metadata when navigating to `FlagsAttribute`:

[image: wrong start of file]

Does anyone know why it might be doing this and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a bug reported in Visual Studio with selecting text in the editor a few months ago. I had thought it was resolved with a recent patch however I could be wrong. I was one of the lucky ones who didn't have, or notice this issue myself.

If you just click with your mouse (not holding the mouse down) to the left of the text you want to select, and then 'shift click' to the right of the text so as to select it, do you get the same issue when using your shortcut (F12) key to go to the definition?

Comment: To be honest, I've upgraded to VS 2022 preview 5 now and it seems to have fixed the problem, not to mention the fact that there is now an option to actually disable navigation to source link and embedded sources, going back to the old behaviour, which works too.

Comment: Upgrading VS2022 did not fix this problem for me.  I now have v.17.6.2 and it's still going to the top of the source.  This is very annoying.  I can click ctrl-minus which positions the cursor at the correct place, but that's an additional, unnecessary step.